# what is the difference between angular.bootstrap and angularAMD.bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-amd

I want to know what is the basic difference between angular.bootstrap and angularAMD.bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses Inversion of Control with Dependency injection, while angularAMD uses AMD which is implemented with RequireJS.

Three common ways of managing dependencies are commonJS, AMD, and dependency injection.

example implementations of these specs are node, browserify, webpack (commonJS), and require (AMD). Note webpack allows the user to choose btw commonJS or AMD syntax.